# Can't open VirtualBox in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I tried opening VirtualBox from the terminal in Ubuntu 18.04. Results of `virtualbox` :

```
/usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox: error while loading shared libraries:  
libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Which VB version did you install? It looks you downloaded a wrong one for 18.04.

Comment: Here's some more information about that "generic" error "cannot open shared object file": https://itsfoss.com/solve-open-shared-object-file-quick-tip/
It is either indicating that you don't have libQT installed or as other commenter said you have an incorrect installation.  QT is a windowing toolkit (https://www.qt.io/).

Comment: Open  a terminal window and run `sudo apt install libqt5core5a`. Retry running VB.

Comment: @Kulfy Most likely OP downloaded a version for 20.04. There is VB available for 18.04 using QT4.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes. But libQt5Core.so.5 is provided by libqt5core5a and according to [Ubuntu Package Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libqt5core5a&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all), it's available in 18.04 as well.

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestions. I have solved the problem and is very happy. Reinstalled libdouble-conversion.so.1:  (When I installed first it wasn't perfect so i do again) As I said I also needed to reinstall lib...so.1:  after I reinstalled lib....so.5: